# Values don't get entered into the database

Tags: php, mysql

Maybe this sounds odd, but I have the feeling I am doing something wrong in my code. I did test it locally and it worked fine, however, when I try to send the data online, it doesn't get entered into the database. I don't know what I am doing wrong at the moment, and I can't see the error (might have looked to much to the code or something like that). Sometimes a fresh look might help better.

The HTML:

```
<form method="post" class="signin" action="inc/actions/processing.php">
        <fieldset class="textbox">
            <label class="username">
                <span>Username</span>
                <input id="username" name="username" value="" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="username">
            </label>
            <label class="charactername">
                <span>Charactername</span>
                <input id="charactername" name="charactername" value="" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Your character's first name">
            </label>
            <label class="password">
                <span>Password</span>
                <input id="password" name="password" value="" type="password" placeholder="Password">
            </label>
            <button class="submit button" name="RegisterUser" type="submit">Register User</button> 
        </fieldset>
  </form>
```

The PHP, processing part:

```
if(isset($_POST['RegisterUser'])){
        $Username = $_POST['username'];
        $Pass_nomdf5 = $_POST['password'];
        $Password = md5($Pass_nomdf5);
        $Charactername = $_POST['charactername'];       
        RegisterMember($Charactername,$Username,$Password);
        CloseConnection();
        header( "Location: http://" . strip_tags( $_SERVER ['HTTP_HOST'] ) . "/newHolo/" );
        exit;           
}
```

The PHP for the `RegisterMember` function:

```
function RegisterMember($Charactername,$Username,$Password){
    $query = "INSERT INTO User(CharacterFname,Username,Password) VALUES ('".$Charactername."','".$Username."','".$Password."');";
    SendQuery($query);
}
```

I ran it over quite a few times, but I have the feeling it's a setting in my database that screws me. I switched all the `NOT_NULL`s to `NULL`s, except for the ID fields (see pic of database table below).

[image]
I am just not sure where my error is, cause locally it ran fine before i uploaded it. I did run though on an older version of PHP, and I have a feeling it might have to do with that as well. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Echo up the query and try to run that in SQL console of PHPMYADMIn

Comment: And you are sure that the username, password (exist on the server and have rights to access the specified database) and database name settings to connect to the mysql database are correct?

Comment: I checked it to your suggestion, techie, and i ran indeed into an error,

#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`darktide_newdarktide/User`, CONSTRAINT `User_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`SgroupId`) REFERENCES `Sgroup` (`SgroupId`))

however, i added the Sgroup, but it still says the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i stated above, it was an sql error that came back, and had indeed nothing to do with my code. I cleared the error message, when I noticed that I didnt fill in any data yet into the datafields of Sgroup.

```
 #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (darktide_newdarktide/User, CONSTRAINT User_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (SgroupId) REFERENCES Sgroup (SgroupId))
```

Dumb, I should have known that if i have a constraint on a field, It should be at least filled with the data. So, i filled up that table, and voila, that did the trick. Thanks for your input people.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you are connecting to the MySQL database!

I use:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "database");
```

to create a link to my MySQL database — I expect you left it out of your question!

If the code is working locally, then I would checking that the 'connection' is working — maybe you have different password or username, because if the code works locally, it should work on your server.

Comment: Actually, that is covered. I run on top an openConnection() function that runs through that whole proces. Thought it wasn't relevant to supply in this case, cause the rest of the functions work within my page. Sorry if I brought some confusion.

Comment: I don't think this is the answer - because I have never tried your technique - plus your answer to Techie sounds like a 'Foreign Key' issue. Any way I am wondering if the $query = "INSERT INTO User(CharacterFname,Username,Password) VALUES ('".$Charactername."' where you are using single quotes then double - is causing the issue and the error being reported is not the right errro. I always stick to use double quotes together or single together.

Comment: It has to do because the data I enter in the fields may contain single quotations. I did it in this query on purpose actually, but thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I've tested it locally and it works for me. (But notice that I have **not set** any foreign key.)

As long as I can see, it seems there's nothing wrong with the code itself, but rather something like the **connection** or something like that.

Is the **connection** OK and has the **database** been **selected**?

```
mysql_connect("servername", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("dababase/schema");
```

On the other hand, is there a foreign key constaint failing?